# how i can select the missing date from oracle table

Tags: select

I have a table `emp_attn (emp_name varchar2(30),attn_dt date)` values like

```
select * from emp_attn;
```

result like

```
EMP_NAME                ATTN_DT        
--------------------    ----------
SAM                     02/05/2013
SAM                 03/05/2013
SAM                 07/05/2013
SAM                 08/05/2013
SAM                 13/05/2013
SAM                 14/05/2013
SAM                 17/05/2013
SAM                 18/05/2013
SAM                 19/05/2013
SAM                 20/05/2013
SAM                 21/05/2013
SAM                 22/05/2013
SAM                 23/05/2013
SAM                 24/05/2013
SAM                 25/05/2013
RAM                     01/05/2013
RAM                 03/05/2013
RAM                 07/05/2013
RAM                 08/05/2013
RAM                 10/05/2013
RAM                 11/05/2013
RAM                 14/05/2013
RAM                 18/05/2013
RAM                 19/05/2013
RAM                 20/05/2013
RAM                 23/05/2013
RAM                 24/05/2013
RAM                 25/05/2013
```

I need the missing `attn_dt` and `name` from this table

Comment: What you mean 'missing'?

Comment: What should be considered the first (expected) attendance date? the last attendance date? Are those specified as arguments or somehow derived from the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dual table for find out missing dates.

Consider below example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5cbc7/10

Here **test** table has 10 rows.

```
Select dat from ( SELECT to_char(SYSDATE + LEVEL, 'dd/MM/yyyy')  dat 
FROM DUAL  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 -- You can change as per your date range 
) a where dat not in (select dates from test);
```

The above select query returns give the result set of not available dates in test table.

You can get the missed date by passing two parameters on this query.

```
SYSDATE - Give your start date

LEVEL (In where condition) - Give as per your date range.
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Dhinakaran, I want with the emp_name,date (Missing Attn. Date

Comment: In your question there are two distinct employee name. You wanna show record missing date with those two employees. For Example, 15/05/2013 to 17/05/2013 record not available. So you need 15/05/2013 RAM, 15/05/2013 SAM like wise till 17. Am i right?